# how to convert timestamp to date in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to convert `1373892900000` to `Monday 2013/07/15 8:55 AM` in Codeigniter.

However, I keep receiving a totally different result by converting the timestamp using the function i have written, please note:*I need to change the dates according to different timezones, that is why I want to write it this way*:

```
public function time_convert($timestamp){

        $this->load->helper('date');

        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        $daylight_saving = TRUE;
        $timezone = "UM4"; //toronto or new york timezone
        $time = gmt_to_local($timestamp, $timezone, $daylight_saving);

        $final_time = standard_date('DATE_RFC822', $time);  
        return $final_time;

    }
```

Result from the above function is: `Sat, 08 Dec 06 01:40:00 +0000`

And if I don't put  `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` in the above function, I get this date instead `Sat, 08 Dec 06 02:40:00 +0100`. My codeigniter seems to default the timezone to Europe/Berlin.

Can anyone please help me correct any of the mistakes I might have made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use PHP's date function?

```
public function time_convert($timestamp){
   return date('l Y/m/d H:i', $timestamp);
}
```

For different timezones use a DateTime object:

```
public function time_convert($timestamp, $timezone = 'UTC'){
    $datetime = new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    return $datetime->format('l Y/m/d H:i');
}
```

Think that should work. Note: I tihnk you need at least PHP version 5.20 for the TimeZone class.

Comment: I need to change the dates according to different timezones.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$time_str=1373892900000;
echo gmdate("fill with your format", $time_str);
?>
```

your format = format your time in php, reading this page for details.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears as though an invocation of [standard_date](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html) with the DATE_ATOM format may sort you:

```
echo unix_to_human(time(), true, 'us'); # returns 2013-07-12 08:01:02 AM, for example
```

There are a whole host of other options for the format, enumerated on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

This how to covert timestamp to date very simple:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', 1299446702);
```

to convert timestamp to human readable format try this:

```
function unix_timestamp_to_human ($timestamp = "", $format = 'D d M Y - H:i:s')
{
   if (empty($timestamp) || ! is_numeric($timestamp)) $timestamp = time();
   return ($timestamp) ? date($format, $timestamp) : date($format, $timestamp);
}

$unix_time = "1251208071";

echo unix_timestamp_to_human($unix_time); //Return: Tue 25 Aug 2009 - 14:47:51
```

if you want to convert it to a format like this: 2008-07-17T09:24:17Z than use this method

```
<?php
 $timestamp=1333699439;
 echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
?>
```

for details about date:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp is coming from javascript on the client, I would guess, because it appears to be in milliseconds. php timestamps are in seconds. So to get the answer you want, first divide by 1000.

Showing the full year would have made the issue more obvious, as you would have seen the year as 45,506.